# typescript extract return types from module

Tags: typescript

There's util `ReturnType` that lets to extract return type of function.
Wondering if there's a way to extract return types from the record (dictionary) of functions e.g.:

```js
const list = {
  function1: (a: string, b: B) => ({ a, b }),
  function2: (c: string, d: D) => ({ c, d }),
  ...
}

type FunctionReturnList = ExtractReturnTypes<list>
```

What `ExtractReturnTypes` would be (if it's possible)?

Comment: What is your expectly? Provide output for your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the values of the `list` dictionary you can define a `ValueOf` lookup type analogous to `keyof`:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

Using this on the `list` value yields a union of all the functions:

```
type Functions = ValueOf<typeof list>;
```

To finally get the union type of all return types of those functions use the [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) utility:

```
type FunctionReturnList = ReturnType<Functions>;

// Creates the following type as a union of all return types:
type FunctionReturnList = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
} | {
    c: string;
    d: number;
}
```

Have a look at this playground [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA3gKBjAZgVzGCgXAEYAuGACgEMroAnBMAcwBoYAjBqZtgJSoAfDXQxanLjAC+A9tjyFipMACYq1YL34cYAEyph8AWy4BTRkJSjq44J32z5mGQG5MmKAE8ADuZgANVo4fHMAeVwAHgAVUTQYgG0Aa3NvEFwYGIBdDy8-AIAxZRJwCFQgkLDIqJ9-DPgkKGE8uqKS1QAlcyh8RjAAGSaK7t7+mIKo4qJSyBbMIA) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer. You can extract the return type of a function using the `ReturnType` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet)

```
type Function1 = ReturnType<typeof list.function1>
```

Is there any reason why you're storing them in a list like that?

*NOTE:* In your example, `list` is actually not a list but a `record` or `dictionary`